# AngularJS: When hovering over key, display its value in a textarea

Tags: angularjs

I have a dictionary defined in AngularJS that looks like this:

```
$scope.examples = [
    {name: 'Key 1', value: "1"},
    {name: 'Key 2', value: "2"},
    {name: 'Key 3', value: "3"}
];
```

I am using ng-repeat to show all three keys in my document.

```
<li ng-repeat="text in examples" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
{{text.name}}
```

When hovering over a Key, I want the key's value to appear in the textarea. I have managed to get a static string in the text field on hover, and I have managed to get a value by index by doing something like this:
`$scope.testWord = $scope.examples[0].value`

but I really want to be able to get the key's value in the textarea. For example, hover over Key 2, and the value of 2 appears in the textarea.

How can I do this with AngularJS?

```js
var app = angular.module('card-builder', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('keyValueExample', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.examples = [
        {name: 'Key 1', value: "1"},
        {name: 'Key 2', value: "2"},
        {name: 'Key 3', value: "3"}
    ];
    
    $scope.hoverIn = function(){
        $scope.testWord = "Static value"
        //$scope.testWord = $scope.examples[0].value
        this.hoverEdit = true;
    };

    $scope.hoverOut = function(){
        $scope.testWord = ""
        this.hoverEdit = false;
    };

});
```

```css
.verse-text-input {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  resize: none;
}

li {
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
li:hover {
    background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
 
<html ng-app="card-builder">
  
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.14"></script>
<script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>

 <body ng-controller="keyValueExample">
   <textarea class="verse-text-input">{{testWord}}</textarea>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="text in examples" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
     {{text.name}}
    <span ng-show="hoverEdit" class="animate-show">
    </span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the value in function, simply pass the `text` object in the function

```js
var app = angular.module('card-builder', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('keyValueExample', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.examples = [
        {name: 'Key 1', value: "1"},
        {name: 'Key 2', value: "2"},
        {name: 'Key 3', value: "3"}
    ];
    
    $scope.hoverIn = function(text){
        $scope.testWord = text.value;
        //$scope.testWord = $scope.examples[0].value
        this.hoverEdit = true;
    };

    $scope.hoverOut = function(){
        $scope.testWord = ""
        this.hoverEdit = false;
    };

});
```

```css
.verse-text-input {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  resize: none;
}

li {
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
li:hover {
    background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="card-builder">
  
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.14"></script>
<script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>

 <body ng-controller="keyValueExample">
   <textarea class="verse-text-input">{{testWord}}</textarea>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="text in examples" ng-mouseover="hoverIn(text)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
     {{text.name}}
    <span ng-show="hoverEdit" class="animate-show">
    </span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>

 </html>
```